# Check if database exists in postgreSQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

I was wondering if anyone would be able to tell me about whether it is possible to use PHP to check if a postgresql database exists?

I am writing a PHP script and I only want it to create the database if it doesn't already exist but up to now haven't been able to see how to implement it.

Thank you

---

I've tried

```
$cmd = 'psql -U postgres -c "SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'portal';"';
    exec($cmd);
```

I got

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'portal'
```

Comment: `\'portal\'` ... but why are you using an exec rather than something like pdo?

Comment: It was a script that I'm trying to put together. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error singe the single quote is used to initalize the statement.

```
$cmd = 'psql -U postgres -c "SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = \'portal\';"';
exec($cmd);
```

You should use PDO instead of exec, but this would probably work for you.

Comment: It doesn't return any kind of results , how do I check it ? Do you have any suggestions for me ?

Comment: If it doesn't return any results (and you know it works for another database that you can test it on), then you can go ahead and CREATE your database if the results of $cmd are empty

Comment: Or I can just use this `$cmd = 'psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS portal;"';`

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `schema` and `database`. in postgres it is schema what you call database in mysql. so if you want to find a database, better use `pg_databases`

```
$cmd = 'psql -U postgres -c "select \'already_there\' from pg_database where datname = \'db1\';"';
    exec($cmd);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a PHP error, you have to escape '\'portal\''